# Migrating jasperServer to another machine

Tags: jasperserver

I have a jasperServer that contains more than one hundred reports in machine1 and I want to migrate it to another machine B. I do not know how to do it. I do not like to configure the new server again. I want to take the jasperServer and put it directly to the other machine.

Is it possible to do it?

Comment: Without knowing the server specs, your JasperServer infrastructure and contents and the possible differences between the servers, hard to tell. Do you know about the *export* and *import* feature in the server admin settings?

Comment: thanks @tobi6 that solved the issue. I have just used the export and import features.